# Bootstrap various section in website overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, bootstrap-4

I have a website that uses a bootstrap template.Now I added comments to my website. My problem is as the comment section grows, the section after it is overlapping with the comments section. This is the code.

```
<div class="container pt-4 pb-4">

    <h5 class="font-weight-bold spanborder"><span>Comments</span></h5>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
{% for comments in ct %}
{% if comments['approved'] == True %}
    <div class="card border-0 mb-4 box-shadow h-xl-300">
            <p>{{ comments['CommentBody'] }}</p>
            <div class="card-text text-muted small">
                 by {{ comments['Author'] }}
         <p></p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container pt-4 pb-4">
    <h5 class="font-weight-bold spanborder"><span>Add your Comment</span></h5>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-4">
                        <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('comments') }}">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputimage">Author</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment_author" placeholder="Comment Author">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="exampleFormControlTextareaSave" rows="3" placeholder="Body" name="comment_body" placeholder="body"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                        <br>

                    </div>
                </div>

</div>
        </div>

    </div>

<div class="container pt-4 pb-4 ">
        <h5 class="font-weight-bold spanborder"><span>Read next</span></h5>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card border-0 mb-4 box-shadow h-xl-300">
            <div style="background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='img/server.jpg') }}'); height: 150px;    background-size: cover;    background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    <div class="card-body px-0 pb-0 d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
      <h2 class="h4 font-weight-bold">
      <a class="text-dark" href="https://www.anygeeks.com/blogging/netlify-vs-github-pages-speedtest">Netlify vs Github Pages Speedtest</a>
      </h2>
      <p class="card-text">
         Github pages and Netlify are among the most popular choices for hosting static sites. Here we compare them on page load times.
      </p>
      <div>
        <small class="d-block"><a class="text-muted" href="./author.html">RahulVk</a></small>
        <small class="text-muted">April 2 2020 &middot; 10 min read</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-xl-300">
    <div class="mb-3 d-flex align-items-center">
      <img height="80" src="{{url_for('static',filename='img/cam.jpg') }}">
      <div class="pl-3">
        <h2 class="mb-2 h6 font-weight-bold">
        <a class="text-dark" href="https://www.anygeeks.com/tech/mi-home-security-camera-review">Mi Home Security Camera 360 review</a>
        </h2>
        <div class="card-text text-muted small">
           by RahulVk
        </div>
        <small class="text-muted">April 10 &middot; 10 min read</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 d-flex align-items-center">
      <img height="80" src="{{url_for('static',filename='img/staticsite.jpg') }}">
      <div class="pl-3">
        <h2 class="mb-2 h6 font-weight-bold">
        <a class="text-dark" href="https://www.anygeeks.com/why-you-should-use-a-static-site-generator/">Why you should use a static site generator ?</a>
        </h2>
        <div class="card-text text-muted small">
           by RahulVk
        </div>
        <small class="text-muted">March 27 2020 &middot; 15 min read</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 d-flex align-items-center">
      <img height="80" src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/blog.jpg')}}">
      <div class="pl-3">
        <h2 class="mb-2 h6 font-weight-bold">
        <a class="text-dark" href="https://www.anygeeks.com/blogging/how-to-install-and-configure-wp-super-cache-plugin-in-wordpress-in-2019">How To Install And Configure WP Super Cache Plugin In WordPress In 2019 ??</a>
        </h2>
        <div class="card-text text-muted small">
           by RahulVk
        </div>
        <small class="text-muted">March 25 2020 &middot; 5 min read</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I use flask as backend and mongodb to store comments. But this looks like a bootstrap problem. Please help

Comment: In your comment loop's if block you're opening two `<div>`s but only closing one. This shows nicely how important proper indentation is.

Comment: @ Chris G, it fixed it.

Comment: Nice, feel free to remove the question then :)

Comment: Shouldn't really nest container in container

Comment: Usually wouldn't hurt, at least in my experience, unless someone forgot to close a tag. But it's off topic. :D